# uploading file so what should i do with headers?

Tags: php, nginx

We successfully set up image uploading on our server with nginx.  Everything gets posted to /upload and then redirects to /file for processing.  The file gets uploaded and stored, but there are headers at the top of the file.

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryqUwBABts5uiLHgDN
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture"; filename="coldplay.jpg"
>
> Content-Type: image/jpeg

What am I to do with this?  Do I strip these headers out with PHP and then save the file again?

Is uploading files with these headers expected behavior?

Here is the form:

```
<form action="/upload/"  id="upload3" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="picture" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="return uploadFiles(this.form);">
</form>
```

and js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function uploadFiles(form) {
          var formData = new FormData(form);

          var url = "/upload/";
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', url, true);
          xhr.onload = function(e) {
            if (this.status == 200) {
              console.log(this.responseText);
            }
          };

          xhr.send(formData);  // multipart/form-data

          return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How are you uploading/storing these files?  Can you show the (PHP) code that you use to store the file?

Comment: The enctype attribute of the `<form>` tag specifies which content-type to use, "multipart/form-data" should be used.

Comment: @MahasishShome: Not if he's using AJAX to post the form.

Comment: The only way for this to happen is if you are writing the *raw* POST body(`php://input`) to a file instead of using `$_FILES['file']`.

Comment: But from what I understand, the nginx upload module handles uploading differently than PHP, so $_FILES is not used.  http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadModule

Comment: Also, this is what I've been following but it's not entirely clear.  In the comments, the author says to cut the headers?  Not sure what this implies. https://coderwall.com/p/swgfvw

Comment: I don't know how nginx works...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using these lines of code to strip the first four lines from our uploaded image files.  I found it somewhere on SO and it works great -- unfortunately I don't know where it was.

```
$line_to_strip = 4;
$new_file = new SplFileObject($file_full_new, 'w');
foreach (new LimitIterator(new SplFileObject($file_full), $line_to_strip) as $line)
    $new_file->fwrite($line);
```

I don't know if this is our permanent solution, however.